# How to change Layout of the Page in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Hell Experts,

I am new to spartacus and trying to customize the page layout. What is the way to change the layout (page structure) as shown in the below picture

[Page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxXtZ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the layout of page templates by creating a custom layout file and using that file as the layout file in `app.module.ts`

You can change the ordering of the slots i.e page structure in your ts file, and adjust the css of the layout from `layout.scss` for your page to look like the one in your photo

You can find the default spartacus layout config file [here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/recipes/config/layout-config.ts)

For example:

**custom-layout-config.ts**

```
import { LayoutConfig } from '@spartacus/storefront';

    export const customLayoutConfig: LayoutConfig = {
      layoutSlots: {
        header: {
          lg: {
            slots: [
              'PreHeader',
              'SiteContext',
              ...
            ],
          },
          slots: ['PreHeader', 'SiteLogo', 'SearchBox', 'MiniCart'],
        },
        navigation: {
          lg: { slots: [] },
          slots: ['SiteLogin', 'NavigationBar', 'SiteContext', 'SiteLinks'],
        },
        footer: {
          slots: ['Footer'],
        },
        LandingPage2Template: {
          pageFold: 'Section2B',
          slots: [
            'Section1',
            'Section2A',
            'Section2B',
            'Section2C',
            'Section3',
            'Section4',
            'Section5',
          ],
        },
        ProductDetailsPageTemplate: {
          lg: {
            pageFold: 'UpSelling',
          },
          pageFold: 'Summary',
          slots: [
            'Summary',
            'UpSelling',
            'CrossSelling',
            'Tabs',
            'PlaceholderContentSlot',
          ],
        },
...
    };
```

**app.module.ts**

```
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
...
layoutSlots: customLayoutConfig.layoutSlots,
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find some information about how to do this in the Spartacus docs for [Page Layout](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/page-layout/) and [CSS Architecture](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/)